# Receiving peer @angular/cli@">= 12.0.0 < 13.0.0" from @angular-eslint/schematics@12.6.1 when upgrading to Angular 13

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

When upgrading to Angular 13, I received "peer @angular/cli@">= 12.0.0 < 13.0.0" from @angular-eslint/schematics@12.6.1" error. After investigation we found that upgrading @angular-eslint/* to next packages will make the upgrade work. (https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/issues/796).

Problem is, we cant use the next versions in production. So needed to understand the repercussions of forcing the build. If not, then removing eslint packages from the package.json.

Regards
CSR

Answer (score 1):

We also delayed the upgrade to Angular 13 for this reason but now ES Lint provides stable 13 versions.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin

You should be able to update now. :)